# Is there an equivalent of Android Overlays for UWP?

Tags: uwp, overlays

Is it possible to overlay a Control (or any UIElement) used in the windows universal platform so it appears on the user's screen regardless on what app he is using? Something similar to: http://www.addictivetips.com/android/overlays-for-android-floating-widgets/

Comment: @Herdo please add that as answer because that's obviously correct :)

Answer (score 4):

***Nope, there isn't!***

Simple reason: the apps written for the *Universal Windows Platform* may run on any device. The current [core library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx), which applies to all devices, doesn't contain any API for your required use-case.
Neither does the any of the [API contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706135.aspx) nor any of the [Device Family specifc contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706137.aspx) offer such an API.

If you want a little bit background information about the **WHY**, you can take a deeper look into this [short introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) about the *Universal Windows Platform*.